# How to set up Dart path?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install http://stagehand.pub

I change my Terminal path to `:/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk`

I check to see if my `PATH` is change and run `echo $PATH` in terminal and I get

```
green:~ king$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk
```

I type `pub global activate stagehand` and the output is `-bash: : command not found`

UPDATED change path to /Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/bin

to set up the path to include pub bin scripts all you do is enter this in terminal right?
$ pub global activate stagehand

Anyways after I did that I tried to continue the tutorial on stagehand.pub and this is the result 
green:~ king$ pub global activate stagehand
Package stagehand is currently active at version 0.1.2.
Resolving dependencies... (2.8s)

args 0.12.0+2
bignum 0.0.6
cipher 0.7.1
collection 1.0.0
crypto 0.9.0
fixnum 0.9.0
path 1.3.0
stagehand 0.1.2
uuid 0.4.1 Precompiling executables... Loading source assets... Precompiled stagehand:stagehand. Activated stagehand 0.1.2. No such file or directory Command: chmod +x /Users/king/.pub-cache/bin/stagehand green:~ king$ cd /Users/king/dart green:dart king$ stagehand -o testapp webapp -bash: stagehand: command not found green:dart king$
Seems the command "stagehand -o webapp" is not found. :/ any suggestion?

My Full .bash_profile is this
export PATH="/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/bin"

My Error is this
-bash: stagehand: command not found green:dart king$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post the contents of your .bashrc/.zshrc?  It will be easier if I can see how exactly your path is setup.

On my system, (because I put the Dart folder in /Applications), the location of the pub binary on my system is:

`/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/bin`

Also in order to execute `pub`, I have to do like so:

`$ ./pub`

Comment: my .bash_profile says

export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/

Comment: Ok well first off, you need to make it: /Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/bin.

Comment: Thanks I got farther but I still did something wrong :( any more errors you see?

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting, and can you post you entire .bash_profile please?  You can modify your original question and add to it.

Comment: Okay updated with error and full bash_profile which is short

Comment: I realized the path in my bash_profile is not how you do it at all. I am using PATH and "" marks SMH I am a NOOB please someone tell me your exact bash_profile content so I can fix this!!! I am clueless

Comment: [Here](http://goo.gl/miwH09) is a gist showing how my path is setup, notice how the bin folder in dart/sdk was the most recent thing I added.

Comment: Any luck?  You can use my .zshrc as a reference for how the dart-sdk/bin folder can be in your path.

Comment: You will also have to add the following to your .bashrc: ```export PATH="$PATH":"~/.pub-cache/bin"```

Comment: I commented on your github also can you show me your 
export PATH="$PATH":"~/.pub-cache/bin"
word for word as I get confused with ~ and $PATH I need to see the real deal my Path word for word is this
export PATH=/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/bin:/Users/king/.pub-cache/bin

Anything wrong with it?

Comment: I updated the gist to show how I have it setup.  Email me at damian.esteban@gmail.com with further questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is 'how to set up dart path.' I'll answer it only.(stagehand is another problem)

1. Download dart-sdk zip.
2. Extract zip.
3. You can see ./dart-sdk/bin
4. From bash, Set ./dart-sdk/bin to your PATH.

   add belows to your `.bashrc`

   > export PATH="$PATH":/your_path/dart-sdk/bin
5. Launch bash again. Alternatively, `source .bashrc`
6. Run `dart` from prompt.

The result should be ...

> dart Usage: dart
>
> Executes the Dart script passed as .
>
> Common options:
>
> --checked or -c   Insert runtime type checks and enable assertions (checked mode).
>
> --help or -h   Display this message (add -v or --verbose for information about   all VM options).
>
> --package-root= or -p   Where to find packages, that is, "package:..." imports.
>
> --version   Print the VM version.

Comment: Thanks the error was I forgot to add the :$PATH at the end of my bash profile. So it suppose to look like this 

export PATH="$PATH":/your_path/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH":/your_path/dart-sdk/bin` is enough. or `PATH=$PATH:/your_path/dart-sdk/bin` and then `export PATH`.

Comment: @SunggukLim comment is enough, and I say this comment is the answer.